# How to make a "Edge Detect Effect" in blender Cycles?

Tags: node-editor, shaders, edges, wireframe

i want to make an Edge detection Effect in blender. all the solutions available online (using geometry pointiness or using bevel node ) provide a smooth edge color , and that's i don't want.

i want somthing like this image

[image]

i tried using wireframe node. it's good , but i don't want all the edges highlighted (the interior edges)
i just want the edges that are not inside a face.

[image]

Comment: You don't want to use Freestyle?

Comment: no because i want to bake the material into a texture,

Comment: baking sharp thin lines to pixel-textures could give you some bad results. Whats the reason for the bake, if i might ask?

Comment: have you tried using a wireframe modifier on a second mesh or a custom second mesh and bake that to the first one, Selected to Active.

Comment: You can achieve such an effect with a toon shader. The black outline is created by a Soldify Modifier, flipped normals, a material that emits black and Backface culling on (https://youtu.be/JavwPNDu04k) But I doubt you can bake this because the line depends on the point of view, doesn't it?